# Constraining a property of type Type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, types, constraints

I'm using a class which serves as a data model for entities in a game i am designing. It stores information about what the entity looks like, how big it is, rules for triggering its collision. Essentially, any static information about rendering the object, or raising its events.

I would like to also have my generic definition include an interchangeable definition for what occurs when the object is loaded, and what occurs every tick when the object is updated.

Its an architecture I intend to implement all over the place in my entire game, but the best example to explain my issue with is Spells.

When a spell is cast in my game, the player contains a reference to an asset stored inside my game. The Asset is an instance of the class `SpellData`. It contains all the fields about its particles, size, appearance, and so forth. I would also like it to contain the functionality of the Spell. To be clear, I do not want the execution of the spell to occur within the scope of the `SpellData`, the spell data is intended to be entirely static. It is meant to simply be a piece of data that other things read from to determine what to do.

Currently, the way I am handling this is I have an interface called `ISpellEffect` which lays out the signature for the `OnStart` and `OnUpdate` methods the Spell will be required to perform.

I then have a series of classes which inherit from `ISpellEffect` such as `HealSpellEffect` which actually contain the definition for these functions. My `SpellData` the contains a field and property which is

`private Type SpellEffectRef  = SpellEffect;`

In the actually asset, this `SpellEffectRef` is set to a value such as `HealSpellEffect` and this is then stored away.

The process which then casts the spell is

1. Player requests the server spawn a new empty Spell object and passes up the reference to the SpellData asset it intends to use
2. The Server injects the Asset and the Player which cast it, as well some other information about the spell like target location and trajectory aimed. The spell is now totally outside the player scope
3. The Spell then reads the `SpellData` for the reference to a `SpellEffect` class. It creates an instance of the `SpellEffect` class, and injects all relevant information about duration, damage values, or other such info as obtained from the Character passed in earlier.
4. The `SpellEffect`'s `OnStart()` is called, and its `OnUpdate()` is set as a coroutine on the Spell's own `Update()` call.

The only problem with this entire design, is that I can not find a way to constrain the `SpellEffectRef` in `SpellData` to only accept values which inherit from `ISpellEffect`. I need this, otherwise I get build error whenever I try to interact with this property or pass it, because creating an instance of it does not explicitly create an `ISpellEffect` please help.

It is very important that all of my functionality and data be plugable like this in order to maintain the separation of concerns, low network traffic, and efficient modular code.

EDIT: MCV Example as suggested

```
public class SpellData \\ Instances of this class are saved as Assets
{
    string AssetId;
    ParticleSystem particleSystem;
    Mesh collisionModel;
    Type SpellEffectRef; \\ Here is where I'd love to have something like where SpellEffectRef : ISpellEffect or something like that
}

public abstract class SpellEffect
{
    Spell parent;
    Character caster;
    SpellData spellData;
    float duration;
    float ticksPerProc

    private float tickEnumerator;
    private flaot procDeltaTime;
    private List<Character> targets;

    public void OnStart();
    public IEnumerator OnUpdate();
}

public class HealSpellEffect : SpellEffect;
{
    public void OnStart()
    {
        parent.Destroy(Duration); //Set the spell to self destruct after its duration
        parent.Transform = caster.Transform; //Moves the Spell to be centered on its caster
    }
    public IEnumerator OnUpdate()
    {
        targets = parent.Collider.GetAllColliders().Where(n=>n is Character && n.Faction == caster.Faction)
        tickEnumerator += 1;
        procDeltaTime += Time.DeltaTime;
        if(tickEnumerator == ticksPerProc)
        {
            foreach member in targets
            {
                member.ApplyDamage(this, .1 * procDeltaTime, Damage.DamageTypeEnum.Healing);
            }
        }
        tickEnumerator = 0;
        procDeltaTime = 0;
        yeild;
    }
}

public class Spell : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Spell(SpellData _spellData)
    {
        spellData = _spellData;
        spellEffect = CreateInstance(_spellData.SpellEffectRef)
    }
    SpellData spellData;
    SpellEffect spellEffect;

    Start()
    {
        spellEffect.OnStart();
    }

    Update()
    {
        StartCoRountine(spellEffect.OnUpdate());
    }
}
```

Comment: How about making SpellEffect an abstract class derived from ScriptableObject? Then, you could drop a field of type SpellEffect on the SpellData

Comment: It does inherit from scriptableobject, but I would like to pass the type directly, since I'm essentially using it as an object delegate. I would also like to harness the power of Object Delegates in other projects as well, which do not have the awesome unit ScriptableObject library. Plus, assets are less space and processor time efficient than using the way I would like. SO in summary, no because general efficiency and neatness as well as versatility and recyclability of the code

Answer (score 0):

I have since resolved this issue, and for anyone who manages to stumble across this, the solution is to use the accessor (specifically its set method) to perform a check that `value is SpellEffect`. Then, in all cases of implementation, you must simply cast it after creating the instance.